# What are the advantages of specifying 'package' properties in JNLP?

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I have notice that you can specify `<package />` properties in JNLP like described here:
http://lopica.sourceforge.net/ref.html#package

What are the advantages of explicitelly defining them over letting the applet classloader do the job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSR-56 spec explains the reasons:

http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr056/index5.html

> **4.5 Package Element**
>
> ...
>
> The package element only makes sense to use with lazily-downloaded
>   resources, since all other resources will already be available to the
>   JVM. Thus, it will already know what packages are implemented in those
>   JAR files. However, it can direct the JNLP Client to download the
>   right lazy JAR resources, instead of having to download each
>   individual resource one at a time to check.